# Compare & Combine multiple models

Tags: predictive-models, forecast-combination

We want to make predictions on customers who are suspected of money laundering. We train boosting models of male and female respectively. (There are 70% of male customers every day.)
We will select 200 samples every day, and make telephone calls to them for further investigation.
I want to ask how to allocate the number of samples for each model. The simplest way is to select 140(200*0.7) for the male model and 60 for the female model. Is there any other way to combine the prediction results of the 2 models and just select the top 200 every day?
Thanks a lot.